# Can we say "encourage somebody to something"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the author mean here?

The Fed's raise was not the only piece of news that could **encourage the world's central banks to a firmer stance.**

source: http://www.businessinsider.com/r-Fed-rate-moves-could-spell-end-to-asian-easing-2017-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual structure should be “encourage somebody to **do** something”.

The article, as is the case with many others - both articles and interviews, has omitted the verb since it is somewhat clear what is meant. This stems from the fact that the whole phrase is *to hold a stance*.

> encourage the world's central banks to [hold] a firmer stance